# Problem with Development Certificate authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, pki

I'm in the process of developing a Web API using .NET Core 3.1 and using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate package.

Here is my Configure Method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app) {
        //if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCertificateForwarding();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

I set up services.AddAuthentication like the following:

```
        services.AddAuthentication(
                CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCertificate(options => {
                options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents {
                    OnCertificateValidated = context => {
                        var claims = new[]
                        {
                            new Claim(
                                ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                                context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                                ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,
                                context.ClientCertificate.Subject,
                                ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                        };

                        context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                        context.Success();

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
                        context.Fail("invalid cert");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

In the applicationHost.config, this is my  element:

```
  <access sslFlags="Ssl, SslNegotiateCert, SslRequireCert, Ssl128" />
```

My application, therefore, requires SSL.

With my certificate on my smart card, the OnCertificateValidated fires without issue.  With a rooted test certificate, I expected the OnAuthenticationFailed event would fire because the default value for options.RevocationMode is X509RevocationMode.Online.  However, with this test certificate, neither event fires at all.

When I set options.RevocationMode to X509RevocationMode.NoCheck, then the OnCertificateValidated event does actually fire for the test certificate; the implication being that before it was failing.  If this is the case, then why didn't the OnAuthenticationFailed event fire.

**Update**

I downloaded the symbols and stepped through the code in CertificateAuthenticationHandler.cs.  The certificate's validation fails and the code runs

```
return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Client certificate failed validation.");
```

but the handler for OnAuthenticationFailed isn't firing.

Any assistance anyone can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Does it have any error message, can it run successfully with a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, the behavior is by design.

As mentioned in my update, the code fires AuthenticateResult.Fail when a certificate does "authenticate" properly; it does not fire the Events.AuthenticationFailed.

I put in an issue on GitHub and they are going to update the code in the next release.

Please see https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30819 for reference